# How can I get a type from an assembly that is loaded from within another folder?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I use the following code:

```
Assembly.LoadFile("the assembly in another folder");
var type = Type.GetType("the full name of the type");
```

Even though the assembly was already loaded before this line of code, it always returns null in `type`.

PS: I did pass in the assembly qualified name, including namespace, type name, assembly name, version and public token.

Comment: Is this `assembly` somehow related to the assembly language ?

Comment: @KirilKirov:  No.  It's a type in .Net.

Comment: @Austin - ah, thanks :) I was misled by the tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Type.GetType` only searches the types in the calling assembly and the types in mscorlib.dll unless you pass the assembly qualified name of the type. [See here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/08/21/454213.aspx)

EDIT

It appears that `Type.GetType` is only able to retrieve `Type` instances from assemblies in the Load context. Assemblies loaded using `LoadFile` are in [no context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) and those loaded using `LoadFrom` are in the Load From context; neither of these contexts allow you to use `Type.GetType` so the resolution will fail. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/05/11/load-contexts-and-type-gettype.aspx) shows that `Type` information can be retrieved for an `Assembly` when the directory it is in is added as a probing privatePath since it will then end up in the Load context but will fail in other contexts.

Comment: i did pass in the assembly qualified name, including namespace, type name, assembly name, and version, public token.

Comment: @CuiPengFei Just to eliminate the obvious, are you certain that the assembly qualified name matches exactly the case-sensitive value that you would get if you statically referenced the assembly and called `typeof(TypeName).AssemblyQualifiedName`?

Comment: @CuiPengFei: I've tried using `Type.GetType` without success, so I would endorse @EvanWilliams answer as the best solution.

Comment: For some reason, the article cited in this reply is no more available - anyone knowing how to get it again?

Answer (score 6):

The "proper" (MS recommended) way to do this, when you must use `Type.GetType(string)` on types in assemblies that are not in the load context but in the load-from or no-context context, is to bind to the [`Appdomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event. The following code is relatively efficient:

```
// this resolver works as long as the assembly is already loaded
// with LoadFile/LoadFrom or Load(string) / Load(byte[])
private static Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var asm = (from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
              where a.GetName().FullName == args.Name
              select a).FirstOrDefault();

    if(asm == null)
         throw FileNotFoundException(args.Name);     // this becomes inner exc

    return asm;
}

// place this somewhere in the beginning of your app:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
```

It appears slightly more efficient to create a combination of the AssemblyLoad/Resolve events to keep a dictionary of the loaded assemblies (use the assembly-name as key).

**On Assembly.LoadFile**
There are some serious drawback on using this method. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx):

> LoadFile does not load files into the LoadFrom context, and does not resolve dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does.

So, if possible, do not use LoadFile. The resulting assembly is loaded in the no-context context, which has even more drawbacks than the load-from context. Instead, use [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) and dependencies will be automatically loaded from the load path.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this....

Assembly.GetAssembly assumes you have an instance of the type, and Type.GetType assumes you have the fully qualified type name which includes assembly name.

you can give path that assembly is located .....

If you only have the base type name, you need to do something more like this:

```
public static String GetAssemblyNameContainingType(String typeName) 
{
    foreach (Assembly currentassembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) 
    {
        Type t = currentassembly.GetType(typeName, false, true);
        if (t != null) {return currentassembly.FullName;}
    }

    return "not found";
}
```

This also assumes your type is declared in the root. You would need to provide the namespace or enclosing types in the name, or iterate in the same manner.

Comment: Take care when loading assemblies because once you load them into an AppDomain you can't unload them anymore. If you have a lot of assemblies to load think about creating separate AppDomain which will do the work of doing the processing assemblies and returning result, after which it can be released.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. Instead, bind to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx) event. That way, you only return the assembly required, where in the above code, you search _each and every loaded assembly, plus you start loading the ones not currently needed_.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing it is to simply trap the return value of Assembly.LoadFile in a variable and call GetType on it like this:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFile("assemblyLocation");
assem.GetType("typeName");
```

You may want to consider keeping a reference to this assembly if you will want to pull types from it often, or do what others have suggested and make a more generic method that loops through all loaded assemblies.