# Moving OData WebAPI controllers to separate assemblies

Tags: reflection, odata, mef, asp.net-web-api2

I have an odata web api project that includes the app_start stuff and global.asax file and would like to put the controllers and models in separate assemblies and not reference them. I've got this working using MEF but am having problems registering them. Eg.

```
builder.EntitySet<PersonModel>("Persons");
```

The approach I've taken is work out what my types are from my loaded controllers ans store these as strings but I'm unable to convert these to types and invoke the ODataModelBuilder.EntitySet method by doing something like this:

```
                MethodInfo method = builder.GetType().GetMethod("EntitySet");
                MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(type));
                genericMethod.Invoke(builder, null);
```

The problem is that Type.GetType(type) returns null since the type is in a separate assembly.

I've no idea whether my current approach will work if I do get over this stumbling block and would appreciate any suggestions of how to achieve splitting my controllers out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the assembly name in the Type.GetType Method. This question is similar to yours:[How can I get a type from an assembly that is loaded from within another folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012724/how-can-i-get-a-type-from-an-assembly-that-is-loaded-from-within-another-folder).

Comment: thanks very much. My issue was that I wasn't loading my assemblies correctly with MEF and so I was able to avoid passing in the assembly name as you suggested.